# matplotlib: alignment of legend title

Tags: matplotlib

In matplotlib, how can I adjust the alignment of the *legend title*? It is always centered, but I need it to be left aligned with the legend box. I tried to change the alignment of the title's Text artist which has no effect. See the following example for details:

```
from pylab import *

x = linspace(0, 1)
plot(x, x, label="1")
plot(x, x**2, label="2")
plot(x, x**3, label="3")
plot(x, sqrt(x), label="square root")

l = legend(title="Title", loc="best")
l.get_title().set_ha("left")               # <== does not work

show()
```

The question boils down to what and who controls the anchor point of the title alignment? Changing the alignment to "right" or "center" has a noticeable effect. Second observation: for long title strings the anchor point moves to the left border of the legend box ...

Comment: The title text is actually "left aligned" by default. The anchor point for the alignment is in the centre of the legend box. Can one specify a different anchor point? Maybe there is a VPacker or HPacker instance associated with Legend?

Comment: For my current case I have a solution: simply say `l.get_title().set_ha("center")`. The text is then centred with the mysterious anchor point (which is roughly between handles and label texts) and it looks good. For a `"Very super long title"`, however, the anchor point moves to the left border of the box ...

Comment: Had the same questions as `set_ha('left')` does not work

Comment: I'm also keen to find a better answer to this question. `set_ha('left')` does not work neither does my other option `plt.setp(legend.get_title(), horizontalalignment='left')`

Answer (score 45):

You may align the complete legend box setting `leg._legend_box.align`. This aligns everything inside the legend box, but the effect is the desired one to have the title on either side of the box instead of the center.

- **Left aligned**

  ```
  leg = plt.legend(title="Title")
  leg._legend_box.align = "left"
  ```

  [image]
- **Right aligned**

  ```
  leg = plt.legend(title="Title")
  leg._legend_box.align = "right"
  ```

  [image]

Answer (score 7):

Since matplotlib version 3.6, there's the `alignment` parameter.
In the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.6.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) you can read:

> alignment{'center', 'left', 'right'}, default: 'center'
>
> The alignment of the legend title and the box of entries. The entries are > aligned as a single block, so that markers always lined up.

You can now simply call

```py
plt.legend(title='Title', alignment='left')
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to displace the `Text` object, using the `set_position((x, y))` method. The units of `x` and `y` are pixels, so you'll have to experiment with what values look right, or use a `Transform`. I'm not sure off hand which combination of `Transforms` might be most useful.

So in short, something like this might work:

```
l.get_title().set_position((-10, 0)) # -10 is a guess
```

Comment: Thanks! set_position() indeed moves the title. However, I would not like to hard-wire the displacement but rather compute it from the box extents. This appears to become pretty involved ...

Comment: This produces inconsistent positioning if you change file formats between .png and .pdf.