# How to align annotation text and legend in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

My current plot has one problem on alignment.
Below is my plot
[image]

What I want is to align align annotation text and legend as shown below
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Below is my plot code.

```
from pylab import *
import re
matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=16) 
matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=16) 
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 16
plt.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 16
plt.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 16
rc('font',family='Arial')


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,4))
x = array([2.2,4.4])
a = array([1,2])
b = array([1,2])
c = array([1,2])
total_width, n = 1, 3
width = total_width / n
x = x - width*1.5



xmarks=[2.2,4.4]

plt.xticks(xmarks)
xx=plt.bar(x, a,  width=width, color='r',alpha=0.5,label='0%')
xy=plt.bar(x + width, b, width=width, color='b',alpha=0.5,label='60%')
xz=plt.bar(x + 2 * width, c, width=width,color='g', alpha=0.5,label='100%')

extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)
leg=ax.legend([extra, xx, xy,xz], ("IOTs replacement\nwith FAC", "0%", "60%",'100%'),loc='upper left')

leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.0)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use the `title` argument for this:

```
leg = ax.legend([xx, xy,xz], 
                ("0%", "60%",'100%'),
                title="IOTs replacement\nwith FAC",
                loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Looks like you need to do some manual adjustments to the position of the legend and the title:

```
leg = ax.legend([xx, xy,xz], 
                ("0%", "60%",'100%'),
                title="IOTs replacement\nwith FAC",
                loc=(-0.035, 0.48))
leg.get_title().set_position((18, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: It is a good improvement, except that there is a white space between the legend and y axis. This means it is actually not in upper left, strictly speaking.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: oops, this is exactly what i want, great!

Comment: There is no need for positioning the legend with cryptic parameters like `-0.035, 0.48` or `18, 0`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872496/4124317).

Answer (score 1):

Legends can have a title which you specify by the `title` argument. The space between the legend and the axes border is dertermined by a parameter `borderaxespad`, which can be set to zero.

To have the legend itself [left aligned in the legend box](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620643/4124317), you may set the legend's `_legend_box.align` to "left".

```
leg=ax.legend([xx, xy,xz], ("0%", "60%",'100%'),
              loc='upper left',
              title = "IOTs replacement\nwith FAC", 
              borderaxespad=0)

leg.get_frame().set_alpha(0.0)
leg._legend_box.align = "left"
```

[image]

Comment: This works great~ Sorry that I can choose only one as the answer, both answers are  quite good...